# How to Fetch Group Admin's Post From a Group using FQL

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-fql

I need to get the feeds which is posted by the group admin from particular group

the following query gives me all the feeds of particular group how to query only admin feeds ?

```
SELECT post_id,message FROM stream WHERE source_id IN (5436729124)
```

If any one know the solution please help me out 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: have you define in table is user or admin?

Comment: A GROUP BY will not help... Is the group public?

Comment: @nitinkachhadiya i dint get you point, by the way the ID ihave given is group id in that query

Comment: Is 5436729124 really the gid of the group?

Comment: @Tobi ya its group ID. i have given a sample gid that not the actual

Comment: can you store admin id in feeds while it post?

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Comment: nope, Actually what i'm trying to do is select a group that i'm part of and from that I need to query all the admin feeds

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work? You mean the admin's own feeds? Then you should write this clearly in your question. And this will only work for their public posts! Remove the `target_id` filter in the query.

Comment: i can able to fetch all the feeds. now i need to fetch only the group admin feeds

Comment: That's not "the feeds", but group posts.. Please be clear what you're trying to achieve. And if you want just the posts of a group whose admins posted to the group, the below query should be fine

Comment: Sorry @Tobi it is group posts

Comment: i need to get the group Posts which is posted by admin

Comment: The below query should do this if the group is public

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
SELECT post_id,message FROM stream WHERE actor_id IN (SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid = 5436729124 and positions in ('ADMIN')) and target_id = 5436729124
```

but I get no results back for the `gid` 5436729124 you gave in your original query. I also can't get results via Graph API like this

```
GET /5436729124
```

so please check.

Comment: Even i dint get any result

Comment: What do you see if you use the subquery? Are you using v2.0 or v1.0 of the Graph API?

Comment: i'm using V1.0 the result i got {
  "data": [
  ]
}

Comment: I guess that FB has an error in the way it handles the queries on `group_member`table. I tested this with a group I'm part of and whose admin I know. Turns out that if I add the filter on `positions in ('ADMIN')´ the query return nothing. Sorry.

Comment: Its ok Thank you for your valuable time

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by using the following query

```
SELECT post_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id IN (126064277584468) AND actor_id IN (SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid = 126064277584468 AND administrator = 'true')
```

Comment: Doesn't work with my group id... But glad that it's apparantly working for you now!

Comment: Yeah, I know, but even the subquery isn't returning anything you my example group, and therefore I shouldn't even need `read_stream` permissions

Comment: I have it, but like I said, it's not even necessary for the subquery on `group_member`

Comment: The code i have given will not work in closed groups

Comment: Sorry @Tobi i don't know but its giving result for me